# Portlet config page doesnt work with PACL

Tags: liferay

I have created a simple portlet using the Liferay MVC framework and have added a **ConfigurationActionImpl** class and **configuration.jsp** for portlet settings.
I have used `<liferay-ui:message>` tag to show labels.

- **Without PACL it works fine.**
- With PACL it is not showing the values mapped to the keys in properties file. It is showing the keys intact. No errors are reported in the console like with other PACL errors.

These two lines are getting printed when i am deploying the portlet

**Attempted to read file global-configuration.properties**

**Attempted to read file C:\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\bin\service.properties**

I have done following entries in liferay-plugin-package.properties

```
security-manager-get-bean-property=\
com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileEntry,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryServiceUtil,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.model.DLFileRank,\
com.liferay.portlet.PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.CacheRegistryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.cache.key.CacheKeyGeneratorUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.language.LanguageUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.configuration.ConfigurationFactoryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.staging.LayoutStagingUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.shard.ShardUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.db.DBFactoryUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.FinderCacheUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.EntityCacheUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.security.auth.AuthTokenUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.service.permission.PortletPermissionUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PropsUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HttpUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.HtmlUtil,\
com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.LocaleUtil

security-manager-services[portal]=\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryService#getFileEntryByUuidAndGroupId,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryService#getFileAsStream,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService#getFileAsStream,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileRankLocalService#updateFileRank,\
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppHelperLocalService#getFileAsStream,\
com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.AssetEntryLocalService#incrementViewCounter,\
com.liferay.portal.service.GroupLocalService,\
com.liferay.portal.service.PortletPreferencesLocalService,\
com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutLocalService,\
com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutSetLocalService

security-manager-files-read=\
${java.io.tmpdir}${file.separator}-,\
${liferay.web.portal.dir}${file.separator}html${file.separator}taglib${file.separator}-,\
${liferay.web.portal.dir}${file.separator}html${file.separator}themes${file.separator}-


security-manager-files-write=${java.io.tmpdir}${file.separator}-
```

Thanks in advance ....

Comment: _I have used tag to show labels_ - what tag? And some code which is showing value and not showing value after PACL would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @PrakashK Thanks for your response. 
I edited the question. I have used liferay-ui:message tag to show the labels in the page.
When I am enabling PACL liferay-ui:message is not working properly.
It shows the keys that I have given instead of the values from properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution as i am missing one thing....

```
security-manager-get-bean-property=\
...,\
com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigFactoryUtil,\
...
```